# LandRover Defender Discontinues

Tags: jaguar

Today morning I came across this sad story.

**Land Rover Defender production to end this Friday (29th Jan 2016).**

Link : http://www.dailypost.co.uk/business/business-news/land-rover-defender-production-end-10790895

Will they introduce an upgrade version of `Defender` ? At least face version like '`Khan`' ?

What could be the reasons behind its **discontinuation** ?

*Please note that I used `Jaguar` as the Site wont allow me to use either `LandRover` or `Defender` as tags. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.*

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm predicting your question will be closed as off topic.  That being said, that's a bummer.  The Defender is the only product they make that I like. I've been in a lot of them and love them.  RIP Defender.  Sad days indeed.

Comment: The site doesn't cover the business aspects of the car industry. Only the technical aspects.  Repair, theory,  etc